# find page by title in extension

Tags: typo3, extbase

In my extension I want to find a page by title.
I try:

```
/**
 * PageRepository
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Page\PageRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $pageRepository = NULL;
```

and then

```
$this->pageRepository->findByTitle('my title');
```

I get the error:

```
Oops, an error occurred: Call to undefined method TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Page\PageRepository::findByTitle()
```

How do I find a page by title?

Comment: You can try with [getRecordsByField()](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/_page_repository_8php_source.html#l01216) method from `\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Page\PageRepository` class.

Comment: @ravisachaniya: make it a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **`getRecordsByField()`** method of `\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Page\PageRepository` class returns the array of page records.

You need to pass page title into 3rd argument of the method as below.

```
$pagesArr = $this->pageRepository->getRecordsByField('pages', 'title', 'my title');
```

> Here is the documentation about the : **`PageRepository Class Reference`** https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_frontend_1_1_page_1_1_page_repository.html#a7943e29e2820497d6e30b1414120075e

Answer (score 3):

Method `findByTitle()` is not provide by `pageRepository`. You can use `getPage()` methods using page `Uid` like below.

```
$this->pageRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Page\PageRepository::class);
$page = $this->pageRepository->getPage($pageId, false);
```